# Invalid column name Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following entity class:

```
public partial class ProjectUser
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

When I perform the following:

```
myDbContext.ProjectUser.ToList()
```

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'ProjectUser'

My `dbcontext` has the following property:

```
public virtual DbSet<ProjectUser> ProjectUser { get; set; }
```

Table script is as following.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectUser]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProjectUser] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

What's wrong? Class has been generated with scaffolding.

Comment: Try ProjectUsers instead of ProjectUser

Comment: could you please add the context you are trying to use .do you have a property of DbSet<ProjectUser> ProjectUser{get;set;}

Comment: doesn't contain definition for ProjectUsers

Comment: public virtual DbSet<ProjectUser> ProjectUser { get; set; }

Comment: Rename DbSet to ProjectUsers

Comment: @ingvar. error changed to: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'ProjectUsers'

Comment: Interesting. Do you have ProjectUser table in your database?

Comment: `ProjectUser` is possibly the name of the table, not the column. Your columns are the properties on your model class. What are you actually trying to do? Query all columns from `ProjectUser` table?

In you r`DbContext`, add `public DbSet<ProjectUser> { get; set; }`

Comment: yes i am trying to get all columns.

Comment: Probably the error just raised from DataAnnotations settings in User or Project models

Comment: @NaDeR. Pls add answer. That is the case. I guess that happened after I updated models using scaffolding. There was annotation of checking that column name. That this column should be in table. But actually that was a table name.

Comment: @AnonymousCreator glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the error just raised from `DataAnnotation` naming settings in `User` or `Project` models.